# onClick doesn't get executed in ViewHolder

Tags: android, onclick, android-viewholder

Last night I was coding and got help on StackOverflow with a onClick event. I finally sorted it out but had to do it differently than the tutorials on the internet and I can't seem to get it working on the right way.

Currently, I have an adapter which has an interface that can be called from my activity. However normally you should implement View.OnClickListener in your ViewHolder and override the onClick method. But the method doesn't get executed, whatever I try to do. Even though I set clickable to true and setOnClickListener on the current ItemView.

My working solution is to add a clickListener in the onBindViewHolder which executes a function in my interface, which is then executed in my activity. Which works.

So anyone, has ANY idea of what could be preventing the onClick from executing? No errors, no warnings... nothing. And maybe a second side question: is the method I'm doing right now a bad method or should it be done with the onClick in the viewHolder?

My viewHolder

```
public class ParkingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    CardView cv;
    TextView parkingName;
    TextView parkingCapacity;

    ParkingViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        itemView.setClickable(true);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        parkingName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.parkingName);
        parkingCapacity = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.parkingCapacity);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        System.out.println("Doesnt get executed");
        // this should work but the system.out doesn't get executed either so problems should be somewhere else
        if(clickListener != null) {
            clickListener.itemClicked(v, getLayoutPosition(), parkings.get(getLayoutPosition()));
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: so the code you posted is working or not?

Comment: @pskink this piece of code isn't working. I have working code however if I add a setOnClickListener in my onBindViewHolder ... but that seems not right since everyone is doing it in the onClick of the viewHolder... I just want to get it working like anyone else does it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.

```
public class ParkingViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    CardView cv;
    TextView parkingName;
    TextView parkingCapacity;

    ParkingViewHolder(View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        itemView.setClickable(true);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        parkingName = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.parkingName);
        parkingCapacity = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.parkingCapacity);


         parkingName.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 System.out.println("executed");

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: It works! Thanks! I wonder what's the difference though :/ anybody an explanation for this?

Comment: @JesseStruyvelt dont create a new `OnClickListener()`, make `ParkingViewHolder` implement `OnClickListener`

Comment: @pskink why?. Implementation is more difficult to make.

Comment: @iamnumber4 what is more difficult to make?

Comment: @pskink you're right. Implement `OnClickListener` is better option.